# Fix scale transform origin to a specific character in a sentence for a scroll zoom effect

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gsap

I'm trying to do a scroll animation where once they reach this part of the page.
[image]

As they scroll it zooms in on the period more and more until it covers the whole screen. Right now I'm using a scale GSAP with a fixed transform-origin. However, this doesn't always have the period as the zoomed part when I resize the screen.

```
              <Tween
                to={{scale: 190, transformOrigin: '33.558vw 11.46vw',}}
                ease={x =>
                 x * x * x
                }
              >
               <div style={{width: '40vw', marginLeft: '15vw', height: '30vh'}}>
                <text style={{fontSize:'5.5vw', fontWeight:'bold'}}>It all starts with a single mem.</text>
               </div>
              </Tween>
```

What is the best practice for implementing this effect? Is there a way to have it always zoom in on the center of the period for any screen size?

Comment: Doing this sort of thing would be easier if you used SVG or a DOM element for the period, if not the whole text section. That way you can calculate where the center of the dot is and scale it appropriately. Here's [a demo](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/QWyLVLO) that does the scaling part.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how would I calculate the center of the dot?

Comment: It depends on how you set it up.

Comment: So if I were to convert the text to an svg. Then wanted to calculate the center of the period. How would I be able to calculate it then set it as the transform origin. Seems that value is set on render and cannot be updated.

Comment: Create a minimal demo of the situation. Try doing it yourself. If you can't get it, post a new question.